# Is the edit queue full?

Tags: support, editing

I ask because I am not seeing an edit link on posts here on Meta.English.

If it's not, why can't I suggest edits on Meta.English? I can do it on the main English.SE site.

Comment: @Mitch: as a 2k user, you obviously *can* edit stuff. Al's talking about proposed edits by low-rep (or even anonymous) users that have to be [peer-reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work).

Comment: @RegDwight: Oh. The context wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The queue isn't full; in fact, there is no queue. The feature simply doesn't exist on SE 2.0 metas. As Jeff Atwood [succinctly puts it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits/78319#78319),

> This is by design — we don't think the metas need this feature.

Comment: I see why I missed it. There is an edit link at meta.stackoverflow. I forgot that that is a special case. All the other sites I visit with any regularity I've already passed the 2000 reputation point barrier and so can edit normally on the meta site.